# "Ruling out" eigenvalues in a superposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics

It recently occurred to me that my knowledge of quantum mechanics doesn't really include anything about measurements that don't return definitive answers.

Some examples might include a system in superposition with 3 eigenstates and a measurement is performed with a negative result (negative meaning it wasn't found), such as looking for the particular eigenvalue associated with eigenstate |1> and not finding it (or maybe a more intuitive example would be a position wavefunction, and making a measurement within only a certain region and **not** finding the particle there).

What I'm wondering about specifically is what can be said, if anything, about the remaining states? We have something like the "Quantum Zeno Effect" for measurements with positive results, but is there anything similar for measurements with negative results?

For instance, if I measure a region and find a particle not to be there, will very rapid successive measurements always return negative results and prevent me from ever observing a particle there? Or similarly, does obtaining a negative result in region A and then performing a very rapid successive measurement on region B increase my odds of finding the particle in region B, effectively meaning the probability elsewhere increases due to region A having been "ruled out" and the fact that the total probability must still equal 1?

Comment: In my opinion, there are two questions in this question that are incompatible: (1) a question about "about measurements that don't return definitive answers", and (2) a question about "measure a region and find a particle not to be there". The second is one where you get a definitive answer: if you measure to see if there is a particle in a particular spot, then the answer is yes or no, definitively. Once the answer is "no", then the wave function "collapses" into one where there is no particle at that spot, and successive measurements result in no particle being at that spot. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) As for measurements that don't return definitive measurements, there is a general theory of measurements that include beyond-von-Neumann (projective) measurements that allow the measurement to be "smeared out" over multiple eigenvalues of an operator.

Comment: This is what my intuition was telling me, but I couldn't find any actual confirmation. Perhaps that's because of the confusion over how to word my searches as you pointed out.

Answer (score -2):

There is no such thing as performing a measurement with a negative result. When performing a measurement, the wave function collapses by definition into one of the eigenstates it is expanded onto.

In your example

> such as looking for the particular eigenvalue associated with eigenstate |1> and not finding it

that is not a measurement: a measurement would be looking for an eigenvalue of operator $\hat{A}$, whatever it is, and writing it down. This means that if you do not find the final state to be (in your example) the eigenstate $|1\rangle$, the wave function will nevertheless be in any other eigenstate, say $|n\rangle$ and *that* would still be a positive outcome of a measurement process.

Your second example is trickier because the position does not have eigenstates, namely every wave function is always everywhere spread in the universe and cannot be localised; however, if we still start from the hypothesis that there are such eigenstates and that the wave function can be expanded onto such a base, by definition, for the eigenfunction to be in the domain of the observables (in this case the position), then at least one position outcome of the basis must be in the domain you are performing the measurement in, therefore even in this case there is no scenario of not finding the collapsed state anywhere: for this description to be consistent, there **must** be at least one eigenstate in your domain onto which the the wave function may collapse.

Comment: This certainly seems to be a clean solution on paper, but I don't see how it could possibly be physical. How can it be that when measuring the position of something I must always simultaneously search every corner of the universe for it? In fact I think even the popular "double slit experiment" in which a scientist might try to measure which slit the particle is going through involves sending other particles to only one slit. If you had a 3-slit experiment I don't see why doing this would tell you exactly which slit it went through rather than just possibly "ruling out" one of the slits.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "physical": you don't "search" every corner of the universe, if somewhere someone detects the particle, then that is a measurement, if it doesn't happen, it isn't (no such thing as a measurement with negative outcome). The double slit experiment is different because the set of states you can expand your wavefunction onto consists of two states (left slit, right slit), not the position eigenstates. In general you must precisely specify what observable you are looking at and what is its eigenset: doing so everything works out.

Comment: You acknowledge that it is in fact possible to search only a subset of possibilities and find nothing, so what I meant by not physical is it seems completely absurd to me that it would have no effect on the wavefunction. Perhaps the issue here is just terminology? Maybe a better way of putting it is that upon finding nothing the wavefunction has been "perturbed"? But surely it must be different now, and surely a rapid successive measurement in the same area wouldn't suddenly yield a measurement, right? So this "ruling out" of particular states must lead to an increase in probability elsewhere

Comment: If the wave function is left the same as before, then (whatever happened in the between) there was no measurement, because, by definition, if there had been one, the wave function would have collapsed into one of the eigenstates of the observable being measured.